Dirty item view being used twice in my custom implementation of BaseAdapter
In my custom implementation of BaseAdapter I have views being hidden and overwritten on the basis of their position. One such condition is based on the last element(The ID will always be -1):
if(employeeData.getRideId().equals("-1") && position != 0 && cabDetails.getRideType().equals("0")) {
        name.setText("Office");
        arrived.setText("");
        arrived.setBackgroundTintList(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorWhite));
        otp.setText("");
        otp.setBackgroundTintList(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorWhite));
        gender.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pickDropTime.setText(new DateTime().Convert24To12Format(cabDetails.getLoginLogoutDateTime().split(" ")[1]));
        call.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 }

The issue I'm facing is that is particular gets applied to the first element as well which I've found to be because of the view recycling pattern used as follows:
if(convertView == null) {
  convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
}

If I revert to inflating the view every time and ignoring the the convertView object passed by getView I get the desired functionality back at the cost of a somewhat laggy scroll at big list sizes. I decided to create my own ArrayList of view that I initialize as null at the creation of the adapter and use the same view recycling logic to retrieve a view from the list if it is not null or creating and storing it in the list otherwise. While this solution also solves my problem better than inflating the view at every instance, I wonder if there is a simpler solution that does away with me trying to maintain a list of views. I'm also using a custom ListView implmentation as detailed in this SO post

obviously there is no else code ... you SHOULD have else code and "undirty" the view there

The else part you refer to I have already done before this block. This block is a special case for ID == -1. My understanding was that if this block is executed at the end of the getView method after all the normal formatting, the last item with ID == -1 would have the formatting as mentioned. Why is it recycling the first view even if it is still visible?
